# ASP.NET MVC form input not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to understand why my page doesn't work as expected.  I was expecting the SignIn method on the controller to be called when clicking submit button, however, StartGame is still be called instead.   The page originates through this URL:  http://{domain}/Play/StartGame

Markup:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Start Game";
}

<h2>StartGame</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("gamerId");
    <input type="submit" value="SignIn" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PlayController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StartGame()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SignIn(string gamerId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the action in your `BeginForm()`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn","Play"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("gamerId");
    <input type="submit" value="SignIn" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Or another option is to create an overload action and use an attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StartGame(string gamerId)
{
      return View();
}
```

Comment: @tatmanblue: Just for clarification. `Html.BeginForm()` will post to the currently rendered action, `StartGame` in this case. If you want to post somewhere else other than the current URL, then you need to specify the route as @mxmissile describes above.